# Как определить часть речи?

Tags: выбор-слов, части-речи

1. Определить часть речи: без пятнадцати два.
2. Как правильно сказать: прийти без пятнадцати два или в без пятнадцати два?

Спасибо.

Comment: 1. Числительное с предлогом

2. Придти без пятнадцати два

Comment: приЙти (!)

Comment: Следуя классике : 

" Дон Гуан.
Ну смотри ж, бездельник.
(Статуе.) Я, командор, прошу тебя
**придти**
К твоей вдове, где завтра буду я,
И стать на стороже в дверях. Что?
будешь?
(Статуя кивает опять.)
О боже!
Лепорелло.
Что? я говорил....
Дон Гуан.
Уйдем."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Здесь три части речи (три слова): предлог **без** и два числительных: **пятнадцать** в родительном падеже и **два** в именительном падеже.
2. Правильно сказать "прийти без пятнадцати два".

Comment: спасибо за ответ! хотелось бы поподробнее - почему употребляется без предлога, ни в одном справочнике не могу найти, а мне нужно обоснование.
к примеру, мы говорим "прийти в три часа", но почему-то "без пятнадцати три".

Comment: Вам что, одного предлога мало, непременно два подавай? Два предлога - перебор) "Авдотья Пална, зашел вас поздравить с днем ангела! Я поиздержался, не одолжите три рубля до Пасхи?"

Comment: г-н грумант, постарайтесь дать развернутый компетентный ответ, без эмоций, придерживаясь рамок культурного общения. мне не мало одного предлога, я пытаюсь найти правило грамматики, в соответствии с которым устанавливаются нормы словоупотребления такого типа конструкций. ваш пример не в кассу.

Comment: Это разговорные обозначения времени-застывшая форма-указание при посредстве предлога без на то, сколько минут (после половины часа) недостает до следующего часа: прийти когда?-без пятнадцати два, без десяти час, без двенадцати десять, и т. п. Эти разговорные выражения  исключают слова минут и часа (хотя может явиться и форма"без семнадцати с половиной минут три"). Здесь математическое мышление - называется только число, собственно числительное, остальное подразумевается.